# When I install the node.js, it gives me some errors.And install failed

Tags: node.js

```
C:\Users\ASUS>npm install -g n
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "n"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.3.0
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@2.1.4: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-03-07T11_09_13_826Z-debug.log
```

This is the error, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the README for [the library you're trying to install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) (which you should always, *always* do!):

> (Unfortunately n is not supported on Windows yet. If you're able to make it work, send in a pull request!)

And sure enough, that's what the error message is telling you:

```
Unsupported platform for n@2.1.4: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

It's saying that the package `wanted` to be installed on a `!win32` platform (in other words, not Windows), but your current platform doesn't meet that requirement.

Comment: Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The package `n` that you're trying to install doesn't have Windows support (as mentioned [in the README](https://github.com/tj/n/blob/d6f4400381ae1659c3ecc8858462122759de8f22/README.md#want-to-install-node-nightly-releases-try-this)).

Comment: @Paul my experience on SO is that most people _never_ read error texts. It would prevent a lot of questions being asked here ;D

Comment: Thank for your help!